# Approach to solve conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am currently working on an exercise, and I am not sure whether I am using a right approach to solve it. The exercise is the following:

> After masks are produced by the factory, they appear in a test center, where they are tested for defects. Historically, only $10\%$ of masks get a positive test result (meaning they are defective).
>
> Let $T_1=$ number of masks tested until first positive result, $T_2=$ number of masks tested until second positive result.
>
> Find $\mathbf{P}(T_2-T_1=k \mid T_1=n)$ and $\mathbf{E}[T_2 \mid T_1=n]$.

Would it be correct to use those formulas:
$$\mathbf{P}(X=x \mid Y=y)=(\mathbf{P}(X=x \text{ and  } Y=y))/\mathbf{P}(Y=y)$$
and
$$\mathbf{E}(X \mid Y=y)=\sum x\mathbf{P}(X=x\mid Y=y)?$$

Comment: Yes, those formulas are true and you can use them to solve the problem.  You will find that the conditional distribution of $(T_2-T_1)$, given $T_1=n$, is a famous distribution. You can also use $$E[T_2|T_1=n] = E[(T_2-T_1)+T_1|T_1=n]$$

Comment: Ok,thank you for answer. However i am still not sure how to calculate P(T2-T1=k|T1=n) properly even if i'd use the formula

Comment: What is your first step to compute $P[T_2-T_1=k|T_1=n]$ using the conditional probability definition of $P[A|B] = \frac{P[A \cap B]}{P[B]}$?

Comment: to compute it using a real values for k and n for eg. 5 and 6? or that wouldn't be right?

Comment: Even simpler, what if you leave it as $k$ and $n$ for now but just do the first step, i.e., plug into the definition.  What do you get?

Comment: $P[T2-T1=k|T1=n]=(P[T2-T1=k and T1=n])/P(T1=n)$

Comment: Good, so, can you compute the denominator?  If you want to first compute it for $n=6$ you can, to get intuition, but you will ultimately need to compute it in terms of a general $n$. We can assume $n \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, ...\}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108306/discussion-between-michael-and-silvija).

Comment: Considering E(X|Y=y) , in my case if the formula says that $E(X|Y=y)=∑ x* P(X=x|Y=y) $ in my case P(T1|T2=n) , if we would take values like k=11 and n=5 , could we compute it this way? $E(N2|N1=n)= ∑ k*(0.9^(k-1)*0.10)$? and then it would like 1*(0.9^(k-1)*0.10)+2*(0.9^(k-1)*0.10)....?